# How do you properly display a Backbone marionette collection view based on a model javascript array property?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

****UPDATE***:  See final answer code in the last code block below.*

Currently I am having an issue displaying a collection in a collection view.  The collection is a property of an existing model like so (pseudo code)

```
ApplicationVersion { Id: 1, VersionName: "", ApplicationCategories[] }
```

So essentially ApplicationVersion has a property called ApplicationCategories that is a javascript array.  Currently when I render the collection view associated with ApplicationCategories nothing is rendered.  If I debug in Chrome's javascript debugger it appears that the categories have not been populated yet (so I assume ApplicationVersion has not been fetched yet).  Here is my code as it stands currently

ApplicationCategory Model, Collection, and Views

```
ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot:"/applicationcategories"
});

ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategories = Recruit.Collection.extend({
    url:"/applicationcategories",
    model:ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategory,

    initialize: function(){
        /*
         * By default backbone does not bind the collection change event to the comparator
         * for performance reasons.  I am choosing to not preoptimize though and do the
         * binding.  This may need to change later if performance becomes an issue.
         * See https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/689
         *
         * Note also this is only nescessary for the default sort.  By using the
         * SortableCollectionMixin in other sorting methods, we do the binding
         * there as well.
         */
        this.on("change", this.sort);
    },

    comparator: function(applicationCategory) {
        return applicationCategory.get("order");
    },

    byName: function() {
        return this.sortedBy(function(applicationCategory) {
            return applicationCategory.get("name");
        });
    }
});

_.extend(ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategories.prototype, SortableCollectionMixin);

ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategoryView = Recruit.ItemView.extend({
    template:"application/applicationcategory-view-template"
});

ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategoriesView = Recruit.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView:ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategoryView
});
```

ApplicationCategory template

```
<section id="<%=name%>">
   <%=order%>
</section>
```

ApplicationVersion Model, Collection, and Views

```
ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersion = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot:"/applicationversions"
});

ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersions = Recruit.Collection.extend({
    url:"/applicationversions",
    model:ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersion
});

ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersionLayout = Recruit.Layout.extend({
    template:"application/applicationversion-view-template",

    regions: {
        applicationVersionHeader: "#applicationVersionHeader",
        applicationVersionCategories: "#applicationVersionCategories",
        applicationVersionFooter: "#applicationVersionFooter"
    }
});

ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersionController = {
    showApplicationVersion: function (applicationVersionId) {
        ApplicationModule.applicationVersion = new ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersion({id : applicationVersionId});

        var applicationVersionLayout = new Recruit.ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersionLayout({
            model:ApplicationModule.applicationVersion
        });

        ApplicationModule.applicationVersion.fetch({success: function(){
            var applicationVersionCategories = new Recruit.ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategoriesView({
                collection: ApplicationModule.applicationVersion.application_categories
            });
            applicationVersionLayout.applicationVersionCategories.show(applicationVersionCategories);
        }});

        // Fake server responds to the request
        ApplicationModule.server.respond();

        Recruit.layout.main.show(applicationVersionLayout);
    }
};
```

Here is my ApplicationVersion template

```
<section id="applicationVersionOuterSection">
<header id="applicationVersionHeader">
    Your Application Header <%= id %>
</header>
<section id="applicationVersionCategories">
</section>
<footer id="applicationVersionFooter">
     Your footer
</footer>
```

One thing to note I am currently using Sinon to mock my server response, but I don't think this is causing the issues as it is responding with the information as I expect looking through the javascript debugger (and like I said it is displaying ApplicationVersion id correctly).  I can provide this code as well if it helps

It is currently displaying the application version id (id in the template), so I know it is fetching the data correctly for normal properties, it just is not rendering my ApplicationCategories javascript array property.

So ultimately I am binding to the success of the fetch for ApplicationVersion, then setting up the view for the ApplicationCategories.  Since this isn't working like I expect I am wondering if there is a better way to create this collection view?

Thanks for any help

**UPDATE: Working code example that Derek Bailey lead me too.**

```
ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersionController = {
    showApplicationVersion: function (applicationVersionId) {
        ApplicationModule.applicationVersion = new ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersion({id : applicationVersionId});

        var applicationVersionLayout = new Recruit.ApplicationModule.ApplicationVersionLayout({
            model:ApplicationModule.applicationVersion
        });

        ApplicationModule.applicationVersion.fetch();

        // Fake server responds to the request
        ApplicationModule.server.respond();

        Recruit.layout.main.show(applicationVersionLayout);

        var applicationVersionCategories = new Recruit.ApplicationModule.ApplicationCategoriesView({
            collection: new Backbone.Collection(ApplicationModule.applicationVersion.get('application_categories'))
        });
        applicationVersionLayout.applicationVersionCategories.show(applicationVersionCategories);
    }
};
```

Comment: if I have looked at things correctly, you do not even fetch the collection anywhere. So what you expect to happen is that the server serves you up with an out-of-the-box collection?

Comment: Well in this case the collection items are being sent in the same payload as ApplicationVersion.  So when I fetch ApplicationVersion it also includes the ApplicationCategories collection along with it, i.e. I don't need to do a separate fetch for the categories collection.

Comment: But is the collection just a javascript array of javascript objects?

Comment: Yeah thats true.  Poor choice of language on my part.  I will update the question

Comment: I was trying to lead you towards the solution below ;) Javascript is a great language for many things

Comment: Ah I see now.  Thanks for your help jakee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Marionette's CollectionView requires a valid Backbone.Collection, not a simple array. You need to create a Backbone.Collection from your array when passing it to the view:

```
new MyView({
  collection: new Backbone.Collection(MyModel.Something.ArrayOfThings)
});
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  Thanks for your help.  I haved added my updated code into my question for future users.