# Tastypie returns string representation rather than valid array for reverse foreignkey lookup

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

**UPDATE: Is the dehydrate within the LocationResource to blame?**

I have an usual situation where a reverse lookup via a foreignkey is returning a nested **string representation** of an array, rather than the array itself. `[I discovered this while using tastypie with backbone.js and backbone.marionette.][1]`

**The strange thing is that this does NOT happen when doing a "forward" or normal lookup, even if there are nested arrays returned from fields.ForeignKey resources**

*For example:*

**Forward lookups:**

```
[{"adult_price": "123", "child_price": "123", "currency": [{"abbrev": "USD", ... }] } ]
//--> notice that "currency" simply returns an array, without " "
```

Reverse lookups - "backwards" via a foreignkey

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "Venice", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/location/1/", 
"theTours": "[{'subtitle': ... ... }]" } ]
//--> notice that there is a set of quotes " " outside the array for "theTours".
//--> a string representation of the array
```

The following is the setup of the resources, and then the models.

**TASTYPIE RESOURCES**

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'location'

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['theTours'] = Tours.objects.filter(location__name=bundle.obj.name).values()
        return bundle
        filtering = {
            'name' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?i)(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]   


class CurrencyResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Currency.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'currency'          
        filtering = {
            'name' : ALL,
            'abbrev' : ALL,
        }               


class ToursResource(ModelResource):
    day = fields.ToManyField(DayOfWeekResource, 'day', full=True)
    location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'location', full=True, related_name="theLocs")
    currency = fields.ToManyField(CurrencyResource, 'currency', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Tours.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'tours'
        limit = 100
        filtering = {
            'day' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'location' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'currency' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?i)(?P<resource_name>%s)/day/(?P<day__day_of_week>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
            url(r"^(?i)(?P<resource_name>%s)/location/(?P<location__name>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name="api_dispatch_list"),
        ]
```

**DJANGO MODELS**

```
class Tours(models.Model):

    location = models.ForeignKey('app.Location', related_name="theTours")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    currency = models.ManyToManyField('app.Currency')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tours"   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class Location(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Currency(models.Model):

    abbrev = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Currencies"  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your model :

```
class Tours(models.Model):

    location = models.ForeignKey('app.Location', related_name="theTours")
    ....
    ....

class Location(models.Model):

    ....
```

You want to use reverse relation like:`Location.theTours.all()`, so you need to add this to `LocationResource` :

```
theTours = fields.ToManyField(ToursResource, 'theTours', full = True)
```

The first `theTours` can be anything you want, the second one should be the same to `related_name`.

No need `dehydrate`.

Final result :

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):

    theTours = fields.ToManyField(ToursResource, 'theTours', full = True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'location'

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?i)(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

Comment: I did that, but since the ToursResource was above the LocationResource, it didn't work. I then explicitly defined the full path in " " (quotes). Now I get: "maximum recursion depth exceeded" when trying to summon the ToursResource. However, once I remove the line - "location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'location', full=True, related_name="theLocs") - it the ToursResource can be summoned, although

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but also need to find out how to avoid the referencing problem.

Comment: "maximum recursuion depth exceeded" thingy is caused by circular dependencies, which caused by `FooResource` that has a `ToOneField` or `ToManyField` with `full = True` point to `BarResource` that has similar thing pointing to `FooResource`. In a simple way: A need B, and B need A. One of the resource need to change its value of `full` to `False`. Another solution to do is to make another resource, a new `FooResource` and a new 'BarResource', this time with `full = False` and have `FooResource` point to new `BarResource`, and new `FooResource` point to `BarResource`.